# Need help identifying a puzzle with a series of rings

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

Any help identifying this puzzle would be greatly appreciated. My wife's grandfather got this puzzle from a relative, we are looking for any information possible.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the [Chinese nine rings puzzle](https://chinesepuzzles.org/nine-linked-rings-puzzle/), the goal is to separate the long-shaped metal piece (in the upper part of your photo) from the "main" part (the one with the plastic base and the rings).

I once heard that in the middle ages the mechanism was used as a lock but I wouldn't be so sure about that.

It's a funny puzzle to solve once you find the mechanism, if you need an hint keep in mind that this puzzle is related to

> Binary code

Comment: I see just 8 rings

Comment: Well, then it's the Chinese Eight Rings puzzle.